# Before-after intervention variation: difference in-difference or broken-stick regression?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, difference-in-difference, change-point

I am trying to figure out which analysis would best answer our research question.

Our study aimed to find out whether the *variation* in surgical rate decreases in a group of hospitals after an intervention in comparison to hospitals whom didn't receive this intervention.
We measured the surgery rate of each individual hospital in each month, from January 2017 - December 2020. The intervention started in January 2018.

- H0 = There is no significant difference in the change in confidence interval between intervention and control group after the introduction of the intervention.
- H1 = There is a significant difference in the change in confidence interval between intervention and control group after the introduction of an intervention.

The data can be easily visualized with 95% confidence interval or spread around the average surgery rate in each group.

What is not clear to me is how to correctly analyze whether the change in confidence interval in the intervention group has changed significantly more in comparison with the change in confidence interval in the control group, corrected for age, sex, comorbidities and socioeconomic status of the patients.

From my understanding

- A difference-in-difference analysis is useful to determine whether the average rate is significantly different in the intervention group after an intervention in comparison to the control group.
- A broken-stick regression is employed to identify the breakpoint in a regression analysis, determining the moment of change for a particular group given a certain value for X.

What is unclear to me is how to accurately analyze whether the change in the confidence interval in the intervention group has significantly changed more compared to the change in the confidence interval in the control group, while accounting for age, sex, comorbidities, and socioeconomic status of the patients.

It appears that a broken-stick regression is similar to a difference-in-difference analysis if one manually sets the breakpoint to a specific date. However, I have not found an answer to our research goal using a difference-in-difference analysis.

Does anyone have experience using these analyses, or is there a different approach to finding the answer to our question?

Comment: Welcome. Is that break point the same for all treated hospitals? If it is, then visualizing the confidence bands is a little easier.

Comment: The break point is the same for all treated hospitals. I do not understand how visualizing the confidence band leads to answering the question "Has the intervention changed variation significantly more in the intervention group than the change in variation in the control group?". 
Could you elaborate?